# How to calculate complexity from special Mergesort

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory, master-theorem

i try to calculate the complexity from Mergesort.
Standard Mergesort has the recursion T(n) = T(n/2)+T(n/2)+n
So its easy to calculate with the Master-theorem.

But my question is, how to calculate  a Mergesort with T(n) = T(2n/3) + T(n/3) + n
and T(n) = T(n-100) + T(100) ?

Can you help me guys?
Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

this two examples are the textbook examples of calculating the recursive equations .

for solving them you need to use "The Recursion Tree" method .

I know that the answer to the first condition is theta(nlogn) and the answer to the second one is theta(n^2) . now to find the solutions , I think you can get a pretty good perspective of The recursion tree in the Introduction to algorithms , CLRS .